# How to make this line

Tags: html, css

l make my first site and have a one question.How to make this line?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sK2cP.png)

Answer (score 1):

Their are many ways you can make those lines. Personally, I would use an `<hr` tag which simply creates a line for you in HTML. Or in CSS, you can give a `border-left:1px solid #FFCE76;` color.